# App to detect when pause/play button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I have been struggling for quite sometime trying to figure out how to have my app detect if the pause/play button was pressed to which I have a counter (uilabel) on my app to add and subtract when the play/pause button is pressed on the headset.

To clarify more , what I am trying to do is once my application detects the pause button on my headphones , it will then add one to my uilabel.. so the pause button would be assigned as a +1 controller for the label

My app does not have any multimedia or background loops as it is not intended for this purpose.  I attempted to use the "UIEventTypeRemoteControl" with no luck since its technically not a remote. Any help would be greatly appreciated regarding this! Thank you

Comment: A little more details would help others better understand this question. Are you developing a media-centric app and the play/pause buttons are UIButton objects of your class? Are you trying to detect external media player's play pause events?

Comment: Yes the physical pause/play buttons would be used the same way as a uibutton

Comment: your app get notify for these play pause events, but for that app has to become first responder for those remote events on headset, otherwise no means to observe these events.